# Hbase Map-Reduce function classpath issues

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am attempting to run the SampleUploader.java code found [here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hbase/hbase-examples/0.98.6-cdh5.3.0/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/SampleUploader.java/?v=source)

I am using HBase 0.98.6-cdh5.3.0 and Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.3.0.

To compile I run:

```
hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main SampleUploader.java
```

But then I get many errors like:

```
SampleUploader.java:24: error: package org.apache.hadoop.hbase does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
```

Aha! I never included the hbase classpath.

So now I try:

```
hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main -cp `hbase classpath` SampleUploader.java
```

All the hbase packages work now, but I get errors like:

```
SampleUploader.java:22: error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
                             ^
SampleUploader.java:23: error: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
                       ^ 
SampleUploader.java:29: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
                           ^
```

Any insight into how I can fix these issues?

EDIT//
I tried to run differently with the instructions [here](https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/how-to-run-and-compile-a-hadoop-program)

After following that method I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.SampleUploader.main(SampleUploader.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing classess are part of hadoop-common jar. Please verify if it is there in the classpath mentioned by you

Comment: Aha, that fixed a bunch. I believe that the `hbase classpath` doesn't include hadoop things... Do you have any idea what the jar for Map-reduce stuff is called? (Job, Mapper, FileInputFormat)

Comment: well there is nothing like jar for map-reduce. There are a bunch of them. If you are using maven, adding this dependency will help you. Other wise, you have to gather the jars yourself. `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
   <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
   <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>'   And please accept the answer if your issue is resolved